# Ubuntu 12.04 had been installed but bootstrapper only loaded Windows 7

Tags: installation, 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, boot-failure

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with DVD, i used "something else and divided hardisk into 2 partition, linuxwsp and / (root). I installed in / and in the last installation, Ubuntu required to eject the disk, i removed the disk and rebooted. But having rebooted, Windows automatically started up and no GRUB was appeared.

How should I dot to fix this troubleshooting.

Sorry, my english is not so well. I'm very grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot using a live cd of ubuntu.
2. Open a terminal and run the command

sudo fdisk -l

It lists the complete partition table of the hard disk. In there, identify which partition you have got your linux installed on. You can identify it using the drive size you had allocated for it and looking at the last column of the output which will be ‘extended’ for all of your linux partitions. The partition will most probably be something like /dev/sda5 or something. Remember this partition.

1. Create a temporary folder in your home directory (Note: You can make the temporary folder anywhere you want. I’m using the home folder just for the sake of explanation). I’m calling it ‘temp’ for now. So that ‘temp’ folder’s path will be /home/ubuntu/temp.
2. Mount your linux partition there. That is, assuming that you found your linux partition to be /dev/sda5, you mount that at the ‘temp’ folder by doing the following command

sudo mount /dev/sda5 /home/ubuntu/temp

1. If you want to check whether you have mounted the correct partition, go to your home folder and open temp. You will be in the ‘/’ directory. In there you will find ‘home’, in which your home folder’s name will be there. Once you’ve confirmed you have mounted the correct partition, do step 6.
2. You have to install grub by showing the system where to read the data from the hard disk at the beginning. Don’t worry, just run the following command

sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp /dev/sda

The ‘/dev/sda’ corresponds to your hard disk name. Replace it by whatever the command ‘sudo fdisk -l’ command showed you.

1. You’re done. You may restart your system.